# Csv empty to export custom attribute from ad users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-csv

From csv file, no problem in powershell console to see the value of the attribute but when I want to export in csv file, the file is empty, maybe someone could help me please ?

```
$adusers = Import-Csv "c:\temp\adusers.csv" -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($item in $adusers) {
# Map variables from CSV
$adusers = $item.'ADUsers'
$Servers = $item.'Domain'


Get-ADUser -identity $adusers -Properties flags -Server $Servers | Select- 
Object -Property samaccountname, userprincipalname, flags | export-csv 
c:\temp\fdfdrff.csv -Encoding Unicode

}
```

File adusers.csv:

```
ADUsers;Domain
account1;Domain1
account2;Domain2
account3;Domain3
account4;Domain4
account5;Domain5
account6;Domain6
account7;Domain7
account8;Domain8
account9;Domain9
```

The output file :

```
"#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"
"samaccountname","userprincipalname","flags"
"account9","account9@Domain9.local",
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the contents of `$adusers` (a collection of objects from your CSV), doesn't match the expected format for `-Identity`.  Given your current code, you should actually be passing `$item`, but even then it may not be correct. Check out the help for details of what is required:  [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Export-CSV` inside `foreach` loop, you have to remember about the `-Append` parameter. Otherwise, each time the file will be replaced which happens in your example.

Also, you can remove assigning the variables and use `$item` properties directly:

```
Get-ADUser -identity $item.ADUsers -Properties flags -Server $item.Domain
```

---

More detailed troubleshooting:

```
$adusers = Import-Csv "c:\temp\adusers.csv" -Delimiter ";"
$adusers
```

If `$adusers` doesn't show the objects correctly, check the file format.

Inside `foreach` run only

```
Get-ADUser -identity $item.ADUsers -Properties flags -Server $item.Domain
```

If AD users are not listed correctly, check if file contains proper identities and/or servers. Accepted identities and/server name formats can be found in [`Get-AdUser` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#required-parameters.).

---

Based on the file you provided:

> The output file :
>
> ```
> "#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"
> "samaccountname","userprincipalname","flags"
> "account9","account9@Domain9.local",
> ```

I can see two things:

- You could use `-NoTypeInformation` to get rid of first line
- As you can see only the last line that means getting data from AD was successful and you only need `-Append` in your `Export-CSV`.

Comment: Please put details about your files in your question. Have you added `-Append`?